# Android how to "force" apply layout

Tags: android-layout, android

Is there any way to force applying a phone UI to the Tablet and opposite? Since android 4.0 there is a possibility (by Android decision) to apply tablet UI's on the phones which is unacceptable.

Is there a way to strictly use only one kind of layout (phone or tablet), for example apply it by user decision (toggle switch or similar control)?

Comment: There's one UI for both tablet and phone. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "tablet" or a "phone" in terms of the Android SDK. There are different screen sizes (small, normal, large, xlarge). You are welcome to use different layouts for those sizes. Android will choose the layout to use based on the device's size. You can also use `<supports-screens>` to control upsizing. But Android will never automatically downsize. Hence, your claim that Android will "apply (large or xlarge) UI's on the (small or normal devices)" is incorrect. If you have evidence to the contrary, please provide source to a sample app and steps to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

//use only one layout and use different drawables

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```